# How to extend a form field vertically?

Tags: php, html

i need to extend a form field vertically.

The form field i want to extend is the "comments" field.

At the moment its currently horizontal on one row.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon the type of form field. If you want to extend the height, use a `<textarea>` for comments as it's height and width are configurable:

```
<textarea name="comments" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Then play with the `cols` and `rows` values. You can also use css to define it's display properties.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understand you right, but you can put the form fields into an list like

```
<ul>
    <li><input...></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

If you want to format a input or textarea field you can use css, or for textareas the html attribute cols and rows.

Comment: I think the best way to explain it is the comment box. Its not one line, it's extended to allows lots of text. I need it like that.

Comment: What html tag are you using, what do you want to do? Give some more input.